# Why is "ObjectId('5efbe85b4aeb5d21e56fa81f')" not considered a valid ObjectId?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am using PyMongo and I am trying to loop through an entire collection and display the ObjectId onto onto my Flask Web Page. However, when I write my method I keep getting the error "ObjectId('5efbe85b4aeb5d21e56fa81f')" is not a valid ObjectId.

The following is the code I am running

```
def get_class_names(self):
        temp = list()
        print("1")

        for document_ in db.classes.find():
            tempstr = document_.get("_id")
            tempobjectid = ObjectId(tempstr)
            temp.append(repr(tempobjectid))
            print("2")
        

        classes = list()
        for class_ in temp:
            classes.append(class_, Classes.get_by_id(class_).name)


        return classes
```

How do I fix this?

**Note**: get_by_id, just takes in an ObjectId and finds it in the database.

Comment: That's not an `ObjectId`, that's just a string that happens to start with the characters 'O', 'b', 'j', etc.  You want to append `tempobjectid` itself to the list, not the `repr()` of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
  tempstr = document_.get("_id")
```

retrieves an `ObjectId` already. You then wrap it again in another `ObjectId` before calling `repr` on that. If you `print(type(tempstr))`, you'll see that it's an `ObjectId`.

Just do `temp.append(tempstr)`.

BTW, you should rename the variable `tempstr` to `tempId` or something more appropriate.